# Is there a function for combining data frames together?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to combine two data frames together that have identical column and row names, but different values for each point. They are essentially replicate experiments. I'd like to merge by rows, but also group the columns together.

Essentially it looks like this:

Data frame 1:

| __ | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| r2 | .5 | 2 | 3 |
| r3 | 3 | 4 | 2 |

Data frame 2:

| __ | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 3 | 5 | 3 |
| r2 | 6 | 2 | 3 |
| r3 | 4 | 1 | 7 |

And I am trying to get an output which looks like this:

| __ | c1 | c1 | c2 | c2 | c3 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 3 |
| r2 | .5 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| r3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 7 |

I have already tried using `cbind()`, `rbind()`, and `merge()`, however both gave not quite the correct results.

`rbind(data_1, data_2)` gave close to my desired output, but the columns were not sorted or grouped together.

Essentially, it gave an output that looked like this:

| __ | c1 | c2 | c3 | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 3 |
| r2 | .5 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 2 | 3 |
| r3 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 7 |

I thought maybe `sort()` or `grouping()` could be a solution, but I was not able to figure out how to use those to get my desired result.

Comment: Note that it is strongly recommended that each variable name in a data frame be unique. The outcome you are looking for wouldn't lead to that.

Comment: As @Phil mentioned, it is a very bad idea to have repeated column names. As a matter of fact, base R will rename the columns so they are unique and trying to create a tibble in tidyverse will throw an error. A better idea is to have a long-formatted data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help!

I ended up using CODER1's answer with slight modifications to get my desired results. It also allowed me scale up the work flow with multiple data frames all with the same column names. I understand that it would be better to have different column names, but I have to work with what I have.

To get it to work I used:

```
    #combine files
    combined <- cbind(df1, df2, ...)

    #order column names
    #for me decreasing = TRUE was what I needed, but I believe that is not necessary
    ordered_cols <- order(colnames(combined), decreasing = TRUE)

    #order combined data frame by ordered column labels
    ordered_combined <- (combined[, ordered_cols])

    #make .csv file if you want
    write.csv(ordered_combined, file = "ordered_combined.csv")
```

This ended up automatically assigning unique column names as well.

I know it's probably not the best code, and I'm sure it can be optimized, but it seemed to work for me. Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

my_pivot <- build_longer_spec(df1, cols = starts_with("c"), names_to = "group")

df1 |>
  pivot_longer_spec(my_pivot) |>
  full_join(pivot_longer_spec(df2, my_pivot), by = c("replicate", "group"))
```

**Output**

```
  replicate group value.x value.y
  <chr>     <chr>   <dbl>   <int>
1 r1        c1        2         3
2 r1        c2        3         5
3 r1        c3        1         3
4 r2        c1        0.5       6
5 r2        c2        2         2
6 r2        c3        3         3
7 r3        c1        3         4
8 r3        c2        4         1
9 r3        c3        2         7
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(replicate = c("r1", "r2", "r3"), c1 = c(2, 0.5,
3), c2 = c(3L, 2L, 4L), c3 = c(1L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(replicate = c("r1", "r2", "r3"), c1 = c(3L, 6L,
4L), c2 = c(5L, 2L, 1L), c3 = c(3L, 3L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to sort the column names, you can instead compute the permutation that reorders the columns as desired, by picking elements 1 and 4, 2 and 5, 3 and 6. Or, more generally:

1, (n + 1), 2, (n + 2), 3, (n + 3), …

where `n` is the number of columns of the first data frame.

In R code:

```
n = ncol(df1)
df = cbind(df1, df2)[rep(seq_len(n), each = 2L) + c(0L, n)]
```

Answer (score -4):

To combine two data frames by grouping columns together, you can use the `cbind()` function in R. However, to achieve the desired output where the columns are sorted and grouped together, you can use the `order()` function to sort the column names and then use the sorted column names to select the columns from both data frames. Here's an example:

```
# Sample data frames
df1 <- data.frame(c1 = c(2, 0.5, 3),
                  c2 = c(3, 2, 4),
                  c3 = c(1, 3, 2),
                  row.names = c("r1", "r2", "r3"))

df2 <- data.frame(c1 = c(3, 6, 4),
                  c2 = c(5, 2, 1),
                  c3 = c(3, 3, 7),
                  row.names = c("r1", "r2", "r3"))

# Sort column names
sorted_cols <- sort(colnames(df1))

# Combine data frames by grouping columns
combined <- cbind(df1[, sorted_cols], df2[, sorted_cols])

# Print the combined data frame
print(combined)
```

Output:

```
   c1   c1 c2 c2 c3 c3
r1  2    3  3  5  1  3
r2  0.5  6  2  2  3  3
r3  3    4  4  1  2  7
```

In this example, the `sorted_cols` variable stores the sorted column names from `df1`. Then, the `cbind()` function is used to combine the columns with the sorted column names from both `df1` and `df2`, resulting in the desired output.

Comment: Great! That helped a lot. However, doing sorted_cols first led to the same problem, but I was able to do it after cbind() and that did it! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for posting this later. It seemed to have worked. Upon further inspection, neither method gave the desired results... for some reason sorting after combining the files simply duplicated the values of the first data frame.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: you could try this one :
# Sample data frames
df1 <- data.frame(c1 = c(2, 0.5, 3),
                  c2 = c(3, 2, 4),
                  c3 = c(1, 3, 2),
                  row.names = c("r1", "r2", "r3"))

df2 <- data.frame(c1 = c(3, 6, 4),
                  c2 = c(5, 2, 1),
                  c3 = c(3, 3, 7),
                  row.names = c("r1", "r2", "r3"))

Comment: # Reset row names to be a regular column
df1$rowname <- rownames(df1)
df2$rowname <- rownames(df2)

# Merge the data frames based on row names
merged <- merge(df1, df2, by = "rowname")

# Remove the rowname column
merged$rowname <- NULL

# Print the merged data frame
print(merged)

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify issues.